# Don't we have `FileUploadToUrl` or something like it?

Tags: c, upload, libcurl

I was wondering if there was an easy function to upload a file to a website (HTTP not ftp ) just like `UrlDownloadToFile` easily downloads a file , or should I use libraries ( like libcurl) ?

Comment: I'd use `libcurl`. Take a look at [this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html)

Comment: Well thanks I know how to work with libcurl, I just wanted to see if there was an easier way.